# jQuery - Run a function after .load() is complete AND DOM is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run a function on an object that is loaded into the DOM when the user clicks on the menu. Here is some part of my code:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function(){  
            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
            //...

            var $newItem = $('<li></li>').appendTo($(columns).first());

            loadContent();
            function loadContent() {
                $newItem.load(toLoad, runScript());
            }

            function runScript() {
                //see the code in IE9's debugger
                alert($newItem.get(0).outerHTML);
                obj.doWidget($newItem.get(0));
            }

            return false;
        });
```

The problem is, when I click on the menu item, the `alert` function in the above code, shows the code before loading: `<li></li>` and not the loaded element from the object itself hence the script changes the old object and the new object overwrites its content. (like I've never ran the script). I assumed that the fallback function should implement return the loaded object. How can I get that object? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a *reference* to `runScript` not the results of executing the function:

```
$newItem.load(toLoad, runScript);
```

Comment: OMG!! I can't believe myself :D Thanks. I was stuck for 1 day straight. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: No problem, sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes `:)`